# Initialize doubly linked list in C, pointers

Tags: c, list, pointers

Is it possible to initiate the value for *preceding and *next on one line of code?

This is the error I get:

```
$ gcc test.c -std=c99
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:34:10: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     n3 = { .value = 300, .preceding = &n2, .next = tail };
          ^
test.c:35:10: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     n2 = { .value = 200, .preceding = &n1, .next = &n3 };
          ^
test.c:36:10: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     n1 = { .value = 100, .preceding = &header, .next = &n2 };
          ^
test.c:37:14: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
     header = { .next = &n1 };
```

Or I need to initiate `.previous` and `.next` separately?

Is it right to set `list_pointer = &header` and last element in the list `.next = tail` which in `turn tail = (struct entry *) 0`? Or are there more convenient ways?

```
 // Prints out the elements of the doubly linked  list, from head to tail and backwards.

#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int            value;
    struct entry   *preceding;
    struct entry   *next;
};

void printPlist(struct entry *list)
{
    list = list->next; // switch from header(start of the list) to n1; because !(header.value) or NULL

    while (list->next) {
        printf("%i\n", list->value);
        list = list->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

    while (list->preceding) {
        printf("%i\n", list->value);
        list = list->preceding;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct entry *tail = (struct entry *) 0;
    struct entry header, n1, n2, n3;
    n3 = { .value = 300, .preceding = &n2, .next = tail };
    n2 = { .value = 200, .preceding = &n1, .next = &n3 };
    n1 = { .value = 100, .preceding = &header, .next = &n2 };
    header = { .next = &n1 };
    struct entry *list_pointer = &header;

    printPlist(list_pointer);  // from head to tail and backwards.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I provided a link to [ulist.h](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utlist.html) in my answer below as well. I recommend downloading it and looking at how they define the macros and also look at their example at the link of how they use the doubly-linked list macros in actual code.

Comment: Here's an example of a linked list macro set they even use in the Linux kernel. Serious coders don't want to have to type all of that stuff every time, so the macros are a big time saver and make the code easier to understand. [Linux Kernel linked list](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define both links in a single line.

```
struct entry
{
    int            value;
    struct entry   *preceding, *next;
};
```

You can use pre-processor macros to make initialization *extremely* concise and convenient.

```
int main() {

    typedef struct LinkedList {
        struct LinkedList   *prev, *next;
        int value;
    } linkedList_t;

    linkedList_t head =  { &head, &head, 0 };
}
```

[ulist.h](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utlist.html) is one of many examples of C linked list macros you can use throughout a program. Makes life a lot easier and I've worked in code shops where they use macros like this consistently throughout a product to make the produce readable, easier to write, more consistent and easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Yellowfun - just added a reference to where you can find macros to study and even use in your own code, and it definitely is a time saver, once you understand how it all works very well, there's no shame in using a good tool to simplify your work..

Comment: @Yellowfun - If your struct is *really* simple, simply using positional arguments rather than naming them is fine and won't confuse anyone. If you start getting several arguments where someone may start to wonder which is which, naming them might be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the [designated initializers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) to re-initialize existing objects.

You can't use them for creating *and* initializing the entire list here either, because the required references to the following or preceeding nodes do not yet exist when the objects are created.

Therefore I'd recommend to add another function to initialize the entries after they've been created. (Or yet another one, that also creates an entry for you using `malloc`.)

See this example:

```
void initializeEntry(struct entry *this, 
                     int value,
                     struct entry *preceding,
                     struct entry *next)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->preceding = preceding;
    this->next = next;
}

int main()
{
    // declare (and create) the list element objects
    struct entry header, n1, n2, n3;

    // initialize the list elements
    initializeEntry(&header, 0, 0, &n1);
    initializeEntry(&n1, 100, &header, &n2);
    initializeEntry(&n2, 200, &n1, &n3);
    initializeEntry(&n3, 300, &n2, 0);

    // print the list
    printPlist(&header);

    return 0;
}
```